# how to create a domain specified cookie in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, subdomain, cookieless

I create a www domain (a domain with a redirect-permanent to www.*) to my web site. And also I create a sub-domain (called static.domain) to my resources (JS, CSS, etc). But my cookies on main domain (www.domain.com) are also sent to static.domain.com how can I set cookies path to just be enabled in www? Thanks in advance.

Comment: by default browser doesn't send any cookie to different domain even example.com to www.example.com

Comment: But it sends right now! Do you have any suggestion please?

Comment: Clear cookies from your browser and then investigate

Comment: OK you are right. I check coockies again and the cookies that are sent to sub-domain were not mine! They were created by google-plus plugin. Have you any idea to block them to send to the sub-domain?